# How to clear all history and disable all plugins and extensions in FireFox 26.0

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-addons, history

I'm trying to [fix a problem](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53074/yahoo-did-some-upgrades-and-the-new-system-basically-doesnt-work-in-firefox?noredirect=1#comment42864_53074) viewing Yahoo and when I went to disable all plugins and clear everything stored I noticed a few surprising things

1) All pages still appear the same even with add-ons such as Adblock plus disabled. Are they disabled? I restarted Firefox after disabling them.

[image: Firefox add-ons setting's screenshot]

They can't possibly be disabled because on this very page Ghostery is blocking things

[image: ghostery still blocking]

2) Even though I cleared "Browsing and download history" and had "everything" chosen for the time, I still have in the address bar past sites I have visited. I noticed each time I clear the history and close Firefox, it doesn't completely close and I need to use the task manager to end the process before closing. Also the clearing of data happens instantaneously so this is suspicious. Am I doing something wrong?

[image: clear history screen shot]

UPDATE: I tried restarting Firefox in safe mode and it appears the add-ons were successfully disabled. For some reason Yahoo still displays incorrectly in Fire Fox (the orange boxes I put there to hide my e-mail =) )
[image: Firefox screen shot]

vs Internet Explorer

[image: IE screen shot]

Comment: Please note that some types of extensions require a Firefox restart to take effect.

Comment: @vWil I remembered to restart Firefox. If you see fit, could you upvote the question so it gets more attention? It sure is strange the add-ons are failing to disable.

Comment: Try using [safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) or [Firefox reset](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems). If you could comment with your results, I may be able to help more.

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy I tried safe mode, see my edit for what happened. I don't want to loose my saved passwords, would that happen if I did the reset?

Comment: Passwords are restored (see 'Firefox reset'), and the reset also saves the old data/folder on the desktop. But (just in case) you can take a manual backup of the password files **key3.db** and **signons.sqlite**, or the entire profile folder before resetting. **Help** (Alt + H) > **Troubleshooting Information:** **Show Folder**, opens the [profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox).